# NodeJS run code in X minutes architecture

Tags: node.js, mongodb, architecture, cron, queue

I want to schedule some code to be run at a variable time. For example, after 60 minutes I want to send an HTTP request to an endpoint and update a database document, but I also want to be able to cancel that code from being ran if an action occurs before that 60 minutes.

What is the best way to architect this? I want it to be able to survive server restarts and also to work if my app is scaled across multiple servers.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are scaling across multiple severs, then you will need some agent that coordinates which server is doing what for timed activities.  There are many different possible approaches and since you've provided little detail about what you're actually doing, it is hard to make a specific recommendation.  You can everything from cron jobs to a custom server that manages a work queue and hands out tasks to other servers to letting the servers get work items directly from a shared database.

Comment: @jfriend00 thank you, just needed some direction. Looking into kue now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `setTimeout()` for that and save the timer ID that it returns because you can then use that timer ID to cancel the timer.  To schedule the timer:

```
var timer = setTimeout(myFunc, 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

Then, sometime later before the timer fires, you can cancel the timer with:

```
 clearTimeout(timer);
```

---

If you want to survive server restarts, then you also need to save the actual system time that you want the timer to fire to some persistent store (like a config file on disk or database).  Then, when your server starts, you read that value from the persistent store and, if it is set, then you set a new `setTimeout()` that will trigger at that time.  Likewise, when the timer fires or when you clear the timer because you no longer need it, you then update the persistent store so there is no future time stored there.

You could make this all fairly clean to use by creating a `persistentTimer` object that had a method for setting the timer, clearing the timer and initializing from whatever persistent store you are using upon server restart.

Comment: What if my app is scaled across multiple servers? If the app starts up on multiple servers, it would duplicate the setTimeouts across servers. Apologies for not mentioning that in original post. I will update.

Comment: @timmyg13 - what are you expecting for an answer?  You obviously have to decide which server is going to service this particular activity.  Including the multiple server part of your question without ANY detail about how that works or what the activity is makes your question far too broad for any specific answer.  And, yes editing your question to include that fact COMPLETELY changes the entire question and now there isn't even close to enough detail to even know what an appropriate answer might be.